# react way of setting focus on a particular button in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, focus

Hi I am new to react and on my page load i need to give focus to a button. I am using functional component. I had seen example with class component and in that using componentDidMount and setting focus using refs.

Here i am using functional component and no ComponentDidMount as well.. How can i set focus on functional component to a button on page load ?

```
export const SubPageHeader=({prop})=>{
return(
<div>
<input type="button"/>
}
export default SubPageHeader
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make use of `useEffect` hook which is equivalent to `componentDidMount`,

```
const SubPageHeader=({prop})=>{
  let textInput = null;
  useEffect(()=>{
    textInput.focus();
  })
  return(
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button" ref={(button) => { textInput = button; }}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-csx8d9)

Comment: I really love this demo but for me am getting Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function :(

Comment: any reason why coming like this @ravibagul91

Comment: any idea if I want to avoid using refs?

Comment: You need to useState for the textInput value

Comment: @ravibagul91 , there's no need to use `useRef` ?

Comment: @ChrisHaines ,  there's no need to use `useRef`?

Comment: How should we do that if we have multiple buttons that are generated in a loop and needs input to be focused on that button click

Answer (score 0):

you can use useEffect instead of componentDidMount to do same thing in functional component.

Use ref on your button element and use it in useEffect method of react to focus button element

Comment: But for using refs we need to use stateful component

Comment: They can't have state, refs or lifecycle methods for stateless components @niks

Comment: you can see this page to get more info.      https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score -1):

For function component you can use hooks, You can use useEffect it is work as ComponentDidMount for functional component.For more detail go through this link :
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html