# How to set focus on a TextField\input using a Formik form when initialValues are passed through\bound to props.object?

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, autofocus, input-field

I have Formik form with this TextField from @material-ui/core:

```
<TextField
    autoFocus
    fullWidth
    name='name'
    label='Name'
    variant="outlined"
    onChange={handleChange("name")}
    helperText={errors.name ? errors.name : "What's your name?"
    error={errors.name}
    touched={touched.name}
    value={values.name}
/>
```

This works great when the form loads for the 1st time with `initialValues` set to an empty `user` object. The Name input will be focused.

However when loading the form with an existing user object (during Edit operation) it loads all the fields correctly but there's no focus anymore.

This form is inside a stateless functional component and `props.user` comes from a parent component.

Any ideas on how to set focus in this case? Is there any place where I can hook up to call focus?

**####### Edit 1 #######**

I tried using [`useEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201088/114029) but it is fired before the input field is actually updated with the value...

```
useEffect(() =>
{
    debugger;

    textInput.focus(); // at this point the input field hasn't gotten the value yet.
})
```

My guess is that I need to hold a `ref` inside the parent component...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working after debugging for some time...

I used a snippet of code taken from [Run side effect when a prop changes w/Hooks](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/z1xzaupgpd-run-side-effect-when-a-prop-changes-whooks) and added a `debugger` statement to be able to check the `input` element:

```
let input = null

useEffect(() =>
{
    console.log('rendered!')

    if (input)
    {      
        debugger;

        input.focus()
    }

}, [props.user])
```

Note the `props.user` passed as argument... this means that anytime `props.user` changes, the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook will fire.

When setting **`ref`** on `<TextField>`:

```
ref={(i) => { input = i }}
```

as shown in many places when dealing with React JS focus, it was trying to focus on the `TextField`'s `<div>` parent element from Material-UI. The real input is inside this `<div>`.

So the correct prop to set in `TextField` is **`inputRef`**:

```
inputRef={(i) => { input = i }}
```

This related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223078/114029) led me in the right direction.

Comment: Isn't your `props.user` going to run `useEffect` whenever it's going to change? I don't think you want to do that after every onChange. Try to add `formikProps.initialValues.user` as a dependency, it'll run upon changing initialValues.

Comment: Yep... after every change, that is, once `props.user` changes I want to focus on the Name `<TextField>`. By the way: `InitialValues` is already assigned `props.user`.